# For Application insights reports - Azure Dashboard Vs PowerBI Dashboard, which one is best?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-dashboard

For dashboards based on Azure log analytics, I see that we have got two options.

- Power BI dashboard based on log query : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/powerbi
- Azure Dashboard based on log query : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-logs-dashboards

Which is recommended ? Why do we have Azure dashboard, as we can do same thing using Power BI dashboard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Dashboard is specific only for Azure , as per the definition

> Dashboards provide a way for you to create a focused and organized
>   view in the Azure portal of your cloud resources. Use dashboards as a
>   workspace where you can quickly launch tasks for day-to-day operations
>   and monitor resources. Build custom dashboards based on projects,
>   tasks, or user roles, for example.

Whereas PowerBI is a separate product by itself,

> Power BI is a collection of software services, apps, and connectors
>   that work together to turn your unrelated sources of data into
>   coherent, visually immersive, and interactive insights

Yes PowerBI will give you flexibility to connect with your external data sources as well as you have n number of visualization , whereas dashboard comes with your Azure portal and hence you dont need to pay separately.

.